# How migrate data safely using BCP and format files with SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, bcp

Are there potential issues using BCP to migrate data after updating table structures ?

If I use this process, will I face data loss?

Export data :

```
bcp MYDATABASE.dbo.MyTable OUT c:\myPath\MyTable.bcp -T -N
```

Create format file to bulk import after changing structure from NCHAR(255) to NVARCHAR(MAX) and skipping some columns :

```
bcp MYDATABASE.dbo.MyTable format nul -T -N -f c:\myPath\formatfiles\MyTable.fmt
```

(Open MyTable.fmt and change data type + skip some columns with this method :
[SQL Server Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms179250(v=sql.100)#methods-for-modifying-a-non-xml-format-file))

Then reimport data with :

```
bcp MYDATABASE.dbo.MyTable IN c:\myPath\MyTable.bcp -f c:\myPath\formatfiles\MyTable.fmt -T -N
```

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 reached end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: Side Note: Depending on which edition and service pack you are running, SQL Server 2008 is out of mainstream support and [quickly approaching end of lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-sql-server-2008?branch=live) for even extended security updates.

Comment: Why do you need to export and reimport if you are just changing columns from `NCHAR(255)` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`?  You can just do that with an `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` statement without data loss.

Comment: Upgrade to higher version and export/import procedure are customer requirements. So, I'm looking for a safe method to export and reimport data with T-SQL script. BCP looks good for that, but as I don't know this tool I prefer asking to do not corrupt data during the manipulation

Comment: I would question the requirement.  A simple alter of the column is way safer than any export / import using any tool.  This sounds like a case of the customer not knowing what's best.